# conversion of enumerator in overloading function

Tags: c++, type-conversion, overloading, enumerator

====================================Edited question===========================
I have read in a book that the conversion of enumerator depends to the number that the enumerator is initialized to.
for EX:in this enum the first enum must convert to int and the second one must convert to double ( because the second one initialized with a number out of range of int.)

```
enum name{A= INT_MAX , B};

void foo(int a)
{
  print "int prameter";
}

void foo(double a)
{
  print "double parameter";
}

foo(B) // must print double parameter, no?
```

well we should  see "double parameter" when we call foo(B) but we will see "int parameter" instead .
why is that?
what is the way of conversion in enumerator?

Comment: With `struct S {int i; char c}; S s;`, it seems obvious that `S *p = &s.a` is wrong, even if `&s` and `&s.a` have same address.

Comment: I didn't understand  exactly what you mean  by struct S { int i; char c}; S s; consider that I am new to c++ and I appreciate   if you can explain more.

Comment: I do the parallell with struct where you might notice the same things. First member has same address as the object (in some conditions), as all `a`, `a[0]`, `a[0][0]` have the same address. Types differs.

Comment: Similar to [whats-the-difference-between-table00-and-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64617513/whats-the-difference-between-table00-and-table)

Answer (score 1):

It's a type issue. `int (*p)[2]` is two dimensional but `a[0]` is one dimensional. So the two aren't compatible. This works though `int* p = a[0];`

Think about how many times you have to dereference (using `*`) to get to the first integer. With `int (*p)[2]` it's twice

```
cout << **p; // print first integer
```

but with `int a[2][2]` and `a[0]` it's only once

```
cout << *(a[0]); // print first integer
```

but twice would be a compile error

```
cout << **(a[0]); // error
```

Comment: what I got is that : int (*p)[2] is a pointer to array that have two integers. the a is the name of array and also a pointer to the first element so here a is a pointer to array which has two element by this fact we could say that int (*p)[2] = a is true but a[0] is the firs element of two dim array and also is the pointer to two integers so when we say int (*p)[2] = a[0] is not true because left operand is pointer to array but right operand is a pointer to integers and we could use &a[0] which means the addres of an array which have two integers.

Comment: sorry if the comment is too much but any way I think I got the answer thank you so much

Comment: @meysamimanipour Your comment above is a reasonable description.