# What's the difference between &table[0][0] and &table?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, pass-by-reference

I've been successfully trying to pass a 2D-array to a function, see code below. What I don't get: Why does my "method C" (see code below) not work?

What's the difference between `&table[0][0]` and `&table`? Both of them point to the same memory address. The former works as argument passed to my function, the latter doesn't, error message:

```
"no known conversion from 'int (*)[3][2]' to 'int *' for 1st argument void print_table(int *table, const int ROWS, const int COLUMNS)
```

Thanks in advance! Alex

```
#include <iostream>
void print_table(int *table, const int ROWS, const int COLUMNS)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++)
        {
            std::cout << table[i * COLUMNS + j] << "\t";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    const int ROWS = 3;
    const int COLUMNS = 2;
    int table[ROWS][COLUMNS] = {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};

    std::cout << (int*)table << "\n";     // these 3 couts all deliver the same memory address      
    std::cout << &table[0][0] << "\n";    // these 3 couts all deliver the same memory address
    std::cout << &table << "\n";          // these 3 couts all deliver the same memory address

    print_table((int*)table, ROWS, COLUMNS);   // method A: Works.
    print_table(&table[0][0], ROWS, COLUMNS);  // method B: Works too.
    print_table(&table, ROWS, COLUMNS);        // method C: Doesn't work! Why?
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The compiler's error message gives you a very readable explanation. Which part of it is unclear to you? The type of `&table` is `int (*)[3][2]`, as the error message helpfully explains. Which cannot be converted to `int *`. C++ does not work this way. `table[0][0]` is `int` (well, `int &`, pedantically), so `&table[0][0]` is `int *`. The End.

Comment: Print table is expecting a pointer to int, while `&table` is the address of table, which is of type `int[3][2]` thus you are sending a pointer to `[3][2]` int array.

Comment: Thank you! If  `int *` = "pointer to int", what would `int (*)[3][2]` be in plain english?

Comment: A pointer to 2D array of ints.

Comment: Thanks both of you! @TonyTannous your addition made it clear to me!

Comment: read https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array where it says array-to-pointer-conversion, and also the more c++ specific section https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array on the same topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Main difference: What is actually being pointed to, and from that its type.

The expression `&table` points to the array `table` itself, and it will have the type `int(*)[3][2]`.

The expression `&table[0][0]` is a pointer to a single element in the sub-array `table[0]`, and will have the type `int*`.

The reason "method A" works, even though it's wrong, is because both pointers just happen to be pointing to the same location.

If we draw out your array then it will look something like this (with "pointers" added):

```
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| table[0][0] | table[0][1] | table[1][0] | table[1][1] | table[2][0] | table[2][1] |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
^
|
&table
|
&table[0]
|
&table[0][0]
```

I added `&table[0]` because this is what plain `table` will be *decaying* to. It will have the type `int(*)[2]`. This is the pointer you pass as "method A". Without the casting to `int*` that method would also fail.

Generally speaking: Whenever you need to do a C-style casting (like for "method A") then you should take that as a sign that you're doing something wrong.

In short: Only "method B" is really correct.

Comment: Pedantically, even method B is UB because of pointer arithmetic: `int[ROWS][COLUMNS]` != `int[ROWS * COLUMNS]`.

Comment: I summarize:  My "method A" is wrong because of deprecated C-style casting;  my "method B" is "undefined behavior" because of pointer arithmetic (which I'm still trying to wrap my head around...)  and my "method C" obviously doesn't work. So what would be your preferred "method D" then?